# SQL: Find all children whose parents are like mine

Tags: sql, subquery

Let's say I want to find out all the children whose parents were in the same class at school as my parents. I can write the query like this:

```
SELECT child.* FROM child
 JOIN parent ON child.ParentID = parent.ID
   WHERE parent.class IN (SELECT parent1.class 
     FROM parent1 JOIN child1
       ON parent1.id = child1.parentID
    WHERE child1.ID = MyID)
```

Somehow this feels like I'm doing it wrong, as I'm writing (approximately) the same join twice, but I can't figure out a way to improve it (I can figure out other ways to nest the subqueries, but none of them seem any neater).

Is there a clean way of doing this that I'm missing? Or am I doing this right?

**Edit:** As GolzeTrol points out in his (complete) answer to this question, it would be odd for children to be restricted to having only have one parent. He is exactly right, and I was not intending to run this query on actual families, but on some other tables, where each child actually is only associated with one parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just join them. You must join both tables twice, to get the related parents and then their children, but other than that it's a simple inner join. I added aliases (which you must anyway in this case) to make clear what the 'role' of each table is.

```
select
  otherkids.*
from
  child me
  /* Join below is weird. I got only 1 parent... */
  inner join parent myparents on myparents.ID = me.ParentID
  inner join parent otherparents on otherparents.class = myparents.class
  inner join child otherkids on otherkids.ParentID = otherparents.ID
where
  me.ID = :MyID and
  otherkids.ID <> me.ID /* Exclude myself */
```

I must say I think it's weird that a child has a ParentID, while I would think a child has a mother and a father, or at least two parents.

Genealogy programs often put a child in a family. So a family has spouses and children. That way, you can connect children even if you don't know their parents (or know only one), and you can easily link people to multiple families if they got divorced and re-married. Might be a suggestion for your table structure too.

Comment: Thanks, that does exactly what I want. Just didn't think of joining a table to itself. Regarding the structure, you're right - I'm not actually doing this for children and parents, but for some tables in my database where children do only have one parent - I will put a note in the question.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @GolezTrol's solution, but you could still solve it your way. To make the query work as you've written it, you should add an outer WHERE clause excluding yourself from the children returned (as per @GolezTroi solution).

Also, although it won't make any difference to execution, it would be more semantically correct to use an '=' rather than 'IN' style subquery as well, as you are only expecting your subquery to return one record (i.e. the one class that your parents were in):

```
SELECT child.* FROM child
 JOIN parent ON child.ParentID = parent.ID
   WHERE parent.class = (SELECT parent1.class 
     FROM parent1 JOIN child1
       ON parent1.id = child1.parentID
    WHERE child1.ID = MyID)
   AND child.ID != MYID
```

Of course there's still the problem that you're using a correlated subquery (i.e. you've joined the subquery to the outer query) and these tend to take longer to process than other methods. As for your point about doing the same join twice, SQL often forces you to do this in more complex queries, particularly ones where you're relating records to other records in the same table.

Comment: Smart thinking with the `=` vs `in`. In this case, the subquery should indeed return 1 record and MySQL is particulary slow with `in`. And with subselects for that matter, so I'd prefer my 'simple join'. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this can solve your problem

SELECT child.* FROM child  INNER JOIN parent ON child.ParentID = parent.ID INNER JOIN parent2 ON parent.class = parent2.class INNER JOIN child2 ON child2.ParentID = parent.ID
WHERE child.ID = myID and child2.ID <> myID

ok try this then :)